# I want to reduce disk usage but don't know which partition is okay to empty

Tags: partitioning, disk-usage, disk

Lately I've been facing a disk error and when I checked the currently used space, this came out:

[image: My Disk Usage]

I see `/dev/md1p1` has the biggest size (877 GB) compared to others. I'd like to know if this partition contains every important stuff, thus shouldn't be emptied, or if it's okay to empty it (partially or whole). And about the other places too, it'd be great to also know which other places are perfectly fine to be emptied, and also the safe way to do so.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please [don't post images of text](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/85695). Instead, copy/paste the text into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) to format it as code.

Comment: it looks like /dev/md1p1 is a LVM volume LVM - Logical Volume Management.. That uses one partition, but then has volume(s) inside it. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm & https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LVM

Answer (score 2):

Your full partition /dev/md1p1 contains every important stuff, so there you are already right.

It also contains (much, much more) stuff you placed there, which, to you, may be equally important, actually even more important! If you erase your own data, you can never recover that. If you erase an operating system, you can simply reinstall it.

So go through your user data and clean up:

- Delete files you do not want or need anymore
- Move files you want to keep, but do not need on a daily base to a different drive
- Leave the files with which you work daily on the drive.

To give you an idea:

- Linux system files rarely occupy more than 25 GB
- Documents, spreadsheets, etc. do not occupy a lot of place - 2 GB is already many, many files
- Music files, photos and especially movies are the big files that can rapidly take up hundreds of gigabytes.

In case I was not clear, the files you should inspect are all you personal files, so they should be in or below your Home folder (typically under "Documents", Movies", etc., but unless we would have access to the drive, you are the only person who can know how you organized your files). If you consider deleting files outside of your home folder, think twice: you may be about to delete important system files.

Comment: what is "it" you refer to? As written this is *extremely* vague and not clearly an answer.